# Piping AD-User Information to CSV

Tags: powershell

I've got some logic/formatting brain block here.

1. I have a CSV with GivenName and Surname Property to use
2. I need to pipe that info against the AD User Estate and Return the information on the users in the list with a few properties including their name, Office, SamAccountName and Email address. I've got as far as this:

   `$employees = import-csv 'c:\employees\employeelist.csv'`

   ```
   $UserInfo = ForEach ($user in $employees) { Get-ADUser -Filter * | `
              Where-Object { $_.GivenName -like
   $employee.GivenName -and $_.Surname -like $employee.Surname 
   }
   ```

The information is returned but not in a table form and i can't believe i cant seem to figure how to pipe it to a CSV, it's not working out, it is returned like this:

```
Reference         : 201111
Surname           : Smith
GivenName         : Name
Effective from    : 24-Sep-13
Business Area     : Client Ops
Department        : ATE
Organisation Unit : ATE Ops
```

Any Ideas why when i  `| export-csv` i don't get the correct format?

Comment: Change `$employee.GivenName` to `$user.GivenName` and `$employee.Surname` to `$user.Surname`, since your loop user `$user`. P.S. You don't need the backtick after the pipe symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you are using the wrong variable name in your foreach loop.
(`$employee` should be `$user`) since that is the variable you define in the loop.

Something like this:

```
$employees = Import-Csv 'c:\employees\employeelist.csv'

$UserInfo = foreach ($user in $employees) { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties GivenName, Surname, Office, SamAccountName, EmailAddress  |
        Where-Object { $user.GivenName -eq $_.GivenName -and $user.Surname -eq $_.Surname } |
        Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Office, SamAccountName, EmailAddress
}

$UserInfo | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\employees\employees.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

As you can see, I'm also naming the properties you want returned, because Get-ADUser by default returns a subset of properties and withour it, you won't get the Office and EmailAddress properties.

Also, I have changed the `-like` operator into `-eq` to fetch exact matches.

P.S. Instead of using the `Where-Object` construction, the code would be more optimized if you use the `-Filter` like:

```
$UserInfo = foreach ($user in $employees) { 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$($user.GivenName)' -and Surname -eq '$($user.Surname)'" -Properties GivenName, Surname, Office, SamAccountName, EmailAddress  |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Office, SamAccountName, EmailAddress
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Theo, superb. Piping with a -Filter * then selecting only some properties the other side of the pipeline was not a good way to retrieve the right info.